# Google chrome not open when vs code launch

Tags: google-chrome, visual-studio-code

I have some trouble with Visual studio code extensions.

When I click on extension "open in default browser" the error below is shown.
If I click on "live server", Google Chrome wont launched either.

Recently I installed Java and this extensions stopped working.

[image: Open browser failed!! Please check if you have installed the browser chrome correctly!]

Answer (score 0):

I was having this same issue with the "open in browser" extension. I clicked on the settings icon and installed an older version 1.1.0. Its working again for me.